# Behaviour of util.format in Node V10 vs Node V11

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to execute util.format with inspect as an object returning a function like

`util.format({inspect: function() { return 1; } })`

Node 10 output:
'1'

Node 11 output:
'{ inspect: [Function: inspect] }'

I couldn't find anything in the documentation in regards to using util.format having an inspect as key. I am not sure why the behaviour is different.

PS: Couldn't have REPL with a older version, so I couldn't attach a reproducible version. But running this code in different node version would show the logs as mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code in Node.js v10 gives:

> (node:39468) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated

You should use `util.inspect.custom` instead of `util.format`
See [Deprecations](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0079_custom_inspection_function_on_objects_via_inspect)